# Fix tooltip mappings in ggplotly with stat = "qq" (QQ normal plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I am trying to use plotly+ggplot to make an interactive Q-Q norm plot and customize the mouse-over text to another vector in my dataframe.

With the default tooltip, I can plot the expected Q-Q norm distribution. When aes text is mapped to customize the tooltip, the stat_qq transformation sets the theoretical quantiles to zero. How can I reproduce the mapping without overriding the stat_qq transformation?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# dataframe with 20 points normally distributed around zero
n <- 20
table <- cbind.data.frame(value = rnorm(n, ),     
                      key = c(letters[1:20]))

## plotly with default tooltip
p <- ggplot(table, aes(sample = value)) +
  geom_point(stat = "qq",
             shape = 21,
             size = 2)
ggplotly(p)
```

[plotly with default tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks6Wu.png)

```
## plotly with customized tooltip mapping 
p <- ggplot(table, aes(sample = value,
                       text = paste0('key is ', key))) +
  geom_point(stat = "qq",
             shape = 21,
             size = 2)
ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

[plotly with custom tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN9tx.png)

```
sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks6Wu.png) LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks6Wu.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks6Wu.png) plotly_4.7.1  ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks6Wu.png) Rcpp_0.12.13        bindr_0.1           magrittr_1.5        tidyselect_0.2.2    munsell_0.4.3       xtable_1.8-2
 [7] viridisLite_0.2.0   colorspace_1.3-2    R6_2.2.2            rlang_0.1.2         httr_1.3.1          plyr_1.8.4
[13] dplyr_0.7.4         tools_3.4.2         grid_3.4.2          data.table_1.10.4-2 gtable_0.2.0        crosstalk_1.0.0
[19] htmltools_0.3.6     yaml_2.1.14         lazyeval_0.2.0      assertthat_0.2.0    digest_0.6.12       tibble_1.3.4
[25] bindrcpp_0.2        shiny_1.0.5         tidyr_0.7.2         purrr_0.2.4         htmlwidgets_0.9     mime_0.5
[31] glue_1.1.1          labeling_0.3        compiler_3.4.2      scales_0.5.0        jsonlite_1.5        httpuv_1.3.5
[37] pkgconfig_2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
After some research, I found a solution around the remapping issue which I adapted from [Paul Rubin](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2016/11/interactive-r-plots-with-ggplot2-and.html). Rather than work with aes mapping, I substituted my labels directly into the plotly object.

```
p <- ggplot(table, aes(sample = value)) +
  geom_point(stat = "qq",
             shape = 21,
             size = 2)
z <- plotly_build(p)
table <- table[order(table$value), ]
table <- table %>% mutate(text = key)
z$x$data[[1]]$text <- table$text
z
```

[plotly with custom text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T07QN.png)